# sum values in different rows and columns dataframe python

Tags: python, dataframe, compare

My Data Frame

```
A B C D  
2 3 4 5  
1 4 5 6  
5 6 7 8
```

How do I add values of different rows and different columns

- Column A Row 2 with Column B row 1
- Column A Row 3 with Column B row 2

Similarly for all rows

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want to do, but you can access any cell of a pandas dataframe with df.iloc[x,y]. You might want to read this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html.

Comment: Could you please add the expected result for your example? Do you want to create a new dataframe or overwrite the existing dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need do this with two columns (and I understand your question well), I think you can use the [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) function.

Your data frame (pandas?) is something like:

```
d = {'A': [2, 1, 5], 'B': [3, 4, 6], 'C': [4, 5, 7], 'D':[5, 6, 8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

So, it's possible to create a new data frame with B column shifted:

```
df2 = df['B'].shift(1)
```

which gives:

```
0    NaN
1    3.0
2    4.0
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

and then, merge this new data with the previous df and, for example, sum the values:

```
df = df.join(df2, rsuffix='shift')
df['out'] = df['A'] + df['Bshift']
```

The final output is in `out` column:

```
    A   B   C   D   Bshift  out
0   2   3   4   5   NaN     NaN
1   1   4   5   6   3.0     4.0
2   5   6   7   8   4.0     9.0
```

But it's only an intuition, I'm not sure about your question!